# AcquireToken Observable errors before returning token

Tags: angular, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, adal

i am using adal-angular4 library for implicit flow implementation in an angular 4 single page application. This app calls a web api to display results. Both applications are hosted in azure (in a specific tenant) and registered appropriately and the configuration works.

The issue i face is when the first call to the API is made the acquiretoken does not immediately come back with the token, it errors out. As part of error handling this makes the page error (conscious decision on my part). But in a few seconds the acquiretoken returns the token. so if i refresh the page after a couple of seconds the api call succeeds and everything works as expected.

Here is the relevant code for various components

```
1. AuthenticationGuard.ts
```

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router, CanActivate, CanActivateChild, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
import { AdalService } from 'adal-angular4';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private adalSvc: AdalService
) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this.adalSvc.userInfo.authenticated) {
        return true;
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}

canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.canActivate(childRoute, state);
}}
```

2. appcomponent.ts

   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { AdalService } from 'adal-angular4';
   import { Router } from '@angular/router';
   import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit
   {
     title = 'My portal';
     isLoggedIn = false;
     loggedInUser: string;
     private bodyTag: any;
     constructor(private adalService: AdalService, private router: Router)
     {
        this.adalService.init(environment.azureConfig);
        this.bodyTag =  document.getElementsByTagName("body")
     }

   ngOnInit() {
       console.log("AppComponent Init");
       this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
       if (this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated) {
       this.isLoggedIn = this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated;
       this.loggedInUser = this.adalService.userInfo.profile.name;
       }
       document.addEventListener("keydown", () => this.handleEvt);
     }

   logout(): void {
       this.adalService.logOut();
     }}
3. LoginComponent.ts

   import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
   import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
   import { AdalService } from 'adal-angular4';
   import { APP_CONFIG, AppConfig } from '../app.constants';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-login',
     templateUrl: './login.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
     })
     export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

   isLoggedIn = false;
     loggedInUser: string;
     localLoggedInUser: any;
     tokenNew: string;

   constructor(
     private route: ActivatedRoute,
     private router: Router,
     private adalService: AdalService,
     @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private appConfig: AppConfig
     ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
       this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
       if (this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated) {
           this.isLoggedIn = this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated;
           this.loggedInUser = this.adalService.userInfo.profile.name ;
         }
     }

   login(): void {
         const returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
           if (this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated) {
           this.router.navigate([returnUrl]);
         } else {
         this.adalService.login();
       }
     }
   }
4. ListService.ts (responsible for making the first API call via the getAll() method.

   import { Injectable, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
   import {Headers, Http,  Response,  RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
   import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
   import '../rxjs-extensions';
   import { APP_CONFIG, AppConfig } from '../app.constants';
   @Injectable()
   export class ProductService  implements OnInit {
     headers: Headers;
     tokenNew: string;
     items: Products[];
     loggedInUserName: string;
     loggedInUserEmail: string;
     baseUrl = 'https://myproductsapi/';
     productListEndpoint = this.baseUrl + '/products';
     constructor( private http: HttpClient, private httpBase: Http,
       @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private appConfig: AppConfig, private adalService: AdalService) {
       this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
       this.setLoggedInUserDetails();
     }

   public getAllProducts(): Observable> {
   return this.httpBase.get(this.productListEndpoint, this.getRequestOptionsWithHeadersForHTTP())
     .map(response => {
       const tmp = response.json();
       return tmp;
     });
   }

private getRequestOptionsWithHeadersForHTTP(): RequestOptions {
    this.attemptAcquireToken();
    this.tokenNew = this.adalService.getCachedToken(this.appConfig.resourceApplicationId);
    const  headersNew = new  Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    headersNew.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.tokenNew);
    const options = new RequestOptions();
    options.headers = headersNew;

`return options;  }

private attemptAcquireToken() {
this.tokenNew = this.adalService.getCachedToken(this.appConfig.resourceApplicationId);
console.log('1. token from attemptacquiretoken ' + this.tokenNew);
// this.tokenNew = null;
if (this.tokenNew == null) {
    console.log('2. token new is null - trying to acquiretoken using adal');
    this.adalService.acquireToken(this.appConfig.resourceApplicationId).subscribe(
      token => {
      console.log('3. token acquired ' + token); //this happens but only a few seconds later
      this.tokenNew = token; }, // never comes
      error => {
        console.log('4. Error when acquiring token'); //this is called straight away
        console.log(error); });
}  }`

How do i ensure that the token exists BEFORE making a call to the API - as it stands, the sequence of method calls made to retrieve product list is as follows

1. Call getAllProducts() - this is the main method responsible for
   calling the API. This initiates nested calls to other methods.
2. getAllProducts() calls getRequestOptionsWithHeadersForHTTP() to get
   RequestOptions (headers) to associate with the http request before
   firing the request to the api endpoint.
3. getRequestOptionsWithHeadersForHTTP() calls attemptAcquireToken() to
   get the token from adal service.
4. attemptAcquireToken() calls acquiretoken() - the method first checks if 
   there is a cached token and if there isnt one, it calls acquiretoken to 
   retrieve one. It is here that the call straight away executes the block of code in "error" lambda - thereby raising an error in the UI. after a few
   seconds the when the acquiretoken has retreived the token it
   executes the code in the "token" lambda.

This only happens the first time a user logs in and there is no token in cache. For subsequent attempts this works fine (retrieving cached token).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise or chain observable like this:

```
private attemptAcquireToken():Observable<boolean> {
    this.tokenNew = this.adalService.getCachedToken(this.appConfig.resourceApplicationId);
    console.log('1. token from attemptacquiretoken ' + this.tokenNew);
    // this.tokenNew = null;
    if (this.tokenNew == null) {
        console.log('2. token new is null - trying to acquiretoken using adal');
        this.adalService.acquireToken(this.appConfig.resourceApplicationId).subscribe(
          token => {
            ...
            return Observable.of(true);
          }, // never comes
          error => {
            ....
            return Observable.of(false);
    }  
}

private getRequestOptionsWithHeadersForHTTP(): Observable<RequestOptions> {
    this.attemptAcquireToken().subsribe(r => {
    if (r !== false) {
            ...
            options.headers = headersNew;
            return Observable.of(options);
        } else {
            return Observable.of(undefined);
        }
    });
}
```

and so on ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed my methods to return Observables. But it errors with "subcribe in not a property". I am sure i am not  returning appropriate Observables or dealing with them correctly in one of the upstream methods - should i be returning Observables through out, all the way upto the main method? Should i be using ".subscribe" for all those Observables? Please see my updated code in the question. Thanks

Comment: @aiguo -  nope. had to revert to my first implementation - which was without promises. it gave me "error" the first time it attempted to acquireToken but subsequent requests went fine. this was in internal application so not much pushback from stakeholders - they live with this for now. but i am more than interested in finding the correct way to do this.

Comment: @nesh_s okay. I'm doing very similar thing and using acquireToken in my route guard just like how you showed above. But, the issue I'm facing is that in the acquireToken success body (i.e. when the token renewel is successful), I am returning Observable.of(true), but no redirect ever happens. I just see a blank page as if route guard is not allowing to process, until I refresh the page again which then takes me to the right page because token is refreshed until that point.

Comment: do you think you can post some code snippet and i can take a look. the redirect seems more like a path/routing issue than the token refresh itself - i may be wrong and a code snippet would be useful here.